# MacOs M1 env cant install php-ext couchbase

Tags: php, couchbase

my env is macos M1 core.
php version: 5.6
I done this: brew install libcouchbase and also libcouchbase@2 installed.
and I cant install the php couchbase extension.

I treid: pecl install https://pecl.php.net/get/couchbase-2.6.0.tgz
It return:

```
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for libcouchbase/couchbase.h... no

./internal.h:57:10: fatal error: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h' file not found
#include <libcouchbase/couchbase.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any ideas?
reinstall libcouchbase is not worded.

Comment: I find the couchbase.h, /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase@2/2.10.9/include/libcouchbase/couchbase.h,  But how can I configure it ?

Comment: step6 is: sudo make && sudo make install

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

1. `wget https://pecl.php.net/get/couchbase-2.6.0.tgz`
2. `tar -xvf couchbase-2.6.0.tgz`
3. `cd couchbase-2.6.0`
4. `sudo phpize`
5. `sudo ./configure --with-php-config=php-config CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libcouchbase@2/include" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libcouchbase@2/lib"`
6. `sudo make && make install`

**NOTE:** Step 5 is most important!